# What is the default level of the log handler?

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

I understand that child loggers inherits level from parent logger.

But given a log handler, with no level, what is the default level for the log handler - does it follow any inheritance?

Comment: When logger level is NOTSET then it inherits the level from its parent. I did not come across such a mention about the log hanlder's default level when NOTSET. So I wanted to get an opinion from other python users

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.setLevel):

> When a handler is created, the level is set to `NOTSET` (which causes
>   all messages to be processed).

In contrast to the [**Logger**'s level](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel):

> When a logger is created, the level is set to `NOTSET` (which causes all
>   messages to be processed **when the logger is the root logger**, or
>   delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger).

So `Handler`s do not follow inheritance and when not specified otherwise, all messages will be logged.